# Is it true that any infinite subset of a non-regular unary language is non-regular?

Tags: automata, infinite-matrices

My question is very similar to this:
[Is there a subset of a non regular language that is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236571/is-there-a-subset-of-a-non-regular-language-that-is-regular)

My claim is that because the subset is infinite, Myhill Nerode says that the language is not regular. 
The first comment on the link above (about palindromes) works for finite subsets, I believe.
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, consider

$$L = \{ a^n \mid n \text{ is prime } \lor n \text{ is even }\}.$$

Clearly this language is non-regular, but

$$E = \{a^n \mid n \text{ is even }\}$$

is infinite, regular and $E \subseteq L$. In fact you can turn any non-regular unary language $X$ into such an example $Y$, e.g. by $$Y = \{a^{2n+1} \mid a^n \in X \} \cup \{a^{2n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I guess it would be off-topic to ask why L is non-regular? All, I can think about is that it is non-regular because it's exponent is prime and produces some sort of infinite non-periodic alphabet. Also,are you stating that n is prime or even? Or, that it is prime *AND* even?

Comment: I think the $\lor$ connective should be clear: $(n$ is prime$)$ OR $(n$ is even$)$. The beginning of the sequence starts $0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,16,\ldots$. As to why it is non-regular, try pumping lemma, it is not even context-free. If you have troubles, then you can pick any undecidable language (e.g. take the standard enumeration of all Turing machines and their inputs $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{M}\times \{0,1\}^*$, and use $X = \{a^n \mid f(n)\text{ halts}\}$), and use the second construction. $Y$ is undecidable, because using it you could answer the questions on $X$.