# Contruct an NFA

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, finite-automata

Construct an automaton that recognizes the following language of strings over the alphabet {a,b}:   {a,bb}  that is only a and bb

Do anyone think that this might be the right approach or has any suggestion to somethin else.

[image: NFA]

Comment: Please be explicit in order to identify the accepting states (it seems that only the green one is)

Comment: There is a very similar example in [Formally prove that every finite language is regular](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216047/formally-prove-that-every-finite-language-is-regular/216075#216075)

Answer (score 1):

Your NFA accepts only a language with a single word, namely $\{abb\}$. So you will need some branching in you automaton to fulfill your purpose.

**Hint:** Since the two words start differently, you need one branch for each.