# Are all finite languages regular?

Tags: computability, regular-language

I've been thinking about this for a while and still cannot come up with a way to show that all finite languages are regular.  I know that all finite languages consist of finite number of strings that are themselves finite and hence there should be either a DFA that recognizes them or a regular expression that can be constructed for each string but I am not sure if this will suffice as proof.

Comment: Yes, it suffices.

Comment: Show that a language consisting of a single word is regular, and show that the union of two regular languages is regular.

Comment: Thanks for the conformation, yes using union is a good idea too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formally prove that every finite language is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216047/formally-prove-that-every-finite-language-is-regular)