# formal languages and computability concepts

Tags: computability, formal-languages

Prove whether or not language

$L$ ={$a^pb^q : p ≥ 100$ and $q ≥ 100$ are fixed integer values, and $i ≥ 0$} is regular.

I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: What is a^pb^q? is it $a^pb^q$ or $a^{pb^q}$?

Comment: is the first one (a^p) (b^q) sorry

Comment: Where does $i$ come into it?

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ and $q$ are fixed values, then the language just has one string, and is [clearly a regular language.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216047/formally-prove-that-every-finite-language-is-regular)

If $p$ and $q$ are not fixed values, but arbitrary values, the question is slightly more interesting. A language is regular iff there exists a corresponding regular expression to it. The following is a regular expression corresponding to $L$

$$ (\underbrace{aaa \ldots a}_\text{100 times})a^* (\underbrace{bbb \ldots b}_\text{100 times})b^*$$

Answer (score 0):

> Prove whether or not language $L$ ={$a^pb^q : p ≥ 100$ and $q ≥ 100$
>   are fixed integer values, and $i ≥ 0$} is regular.

Ignoring $i$, this seems to be a regular language. Here is a NFA for $L = \{ a^p b^q \mid p\ge 3, q\ge 3 \}$, which is easy to modify for a lower bound of $100$ instead of $3$.

[image]