# Proving the language is regular or not?

Tags: automata, regular-language

I was trying to solve these two questions for a while, can I know how can I use pumping lemma to solve them?

a) $\{a^i b^j \mid i, j \geq 0 \text{ and }i + j = 5\}$.

b) $\{w = xy \mid x, y \in \{a, b\}^* \text{ and } |x| = |y| \text{ and } \#a(x) \geq \#a(y) \}$.

and thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE network, please visit [Help Center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Did you really try seriously to solve a) ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I did try and I solve it, I found similar question but with (i doesn`t equal j)

Answer (score 1):

Language a) is regular.

To see this, observe that there are only finitely many strings in this language (all strings of length $5$ such that the string is composed of zero or more $a$s followed by zero or more $b$s). Thus, we can compose a DFA, which has a finite number of accepting states corresponding to these strings, and all other states are not accepting. In general, [any finite language is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216047/formally-prove-that-every-finite-language-is-regular).

Language b) is not regular.

To see this, we need to use the pumping lemma. 
Suppose language b) was regular, and was the language corresponding to some DFA $D$, which has $N$ states. The [pumping length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Proof_of_the_pumping_lemma) of this language must be $\leq N$.

Clearly, $w = b^{N+1}ab^{N+1}a$ is part of this language. Using the pumping lemma on $w$, we need to decompose $w=xyz$, where $|xy|\leq N$ and $|y|\geq 1$. The only way this can happen is if $y=b^i$ for some $i\geq 1$. Then, by pumping $w$, we see that $xy^2z=b^{N+1+i}ab^{N+1}a$ must be in this language, but it is not as the first half of the language contains only $b$s but the second half has at least one $a$.

This is a contradiction, and hence the assumption that language b) was regular is false.

Comment: can you help me in composing the dfa? because I should use pumping lemma first to prove then draw the dfa if it`s possible

Comment: + isn`t this the same as my question, L = {a^ib^j: i, j >= 0 and i not equal j}